# Can't login with Meteor function loginWithPassword, Unrecognized options for login request [400] error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm working on React + Meteor application and can't login using accounts-password package via loginWithPassword function.

The official API says that ***Unrecognized options for login request [400]*** error pops up when your user or password is undefined (or, i guess, just do not match the API), but i've checked the arguments and everything seems correct. username and password are strings. Meteor has ability to operate with user object, but this is not working too. 
Here's the sample of my code.

```
  const submit = useCallback(
(values) => {
  const { email, password } = values;
  const callback = (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      notifyError();
      return;
    }
    login();
    history.replace(from);
  };
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, callback);
},
[from, history, login, notifyError]
```

);

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that particular error can occur when there are no login handlers registered.

Have you added the `accounts-password` package ?

`meteor add accounts-password`

Comment: Yes, i have accounts-password and accounts-base packages installed. Should i register password login service in startup sequence?